# How are messages actually trasferred between local akka actors

Tags: java, akka

I am new to Akka and went through the Akka Documentation. I understood that Actors interact with each other through messages and these messages should be immutable objects. i also got to know that if actors are interacting remotely then messages are passed though the network.

My question is how is a message passed between local actors. If i have a Actor system deployed in just one machine. How does these actors which share the same JVM interact with each other? Is it in-memory interaction?

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's through memory. Specifically, there's a Queue for each actor, and when you send that actor a message, your message is appended to the queue.

The documentation on [mailboxes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/java/mailboxes.html) should help clear this up.